# How often does Google Notifier check for email?

Tags: gmail, google

I just installed Google Notifier (Mac), and I noticed that it's a bit delayed in when it reports an email has arrived.

It seems that it polls the server every X minutes instead of using push technology. How often does Google Notifier check for mail, and is there any way to modify it?

Comment: You could also try Notify (http://notifyapp.com). It's a bit more powerful than Google's notifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe by default it checks every ten minutes.  To adjust the interval, click on the mail icon, then hold down the Command and Option keys and click on Preferences.
A box will pop up asking for a key and value. Use `AutocheckInterval` as the key and type the number of minutes in the value box.  Then click Set and you're done.  You need to restart it for the change to take effect.

NOTE: `AutocheckInterval` is case-sensitive

You can also do the following in Terminal

`defaults write com.google.GmailNotifier AutocheckInterval #`

Replace the `#` above with a number to represent minutes between checks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Griffo's suggestion of using `AutocheckInterval`, you can also undo this change by typing the following in terminal:

```
defaults delete com.google.GmailNotifier AutocheckInterval
```

Comment: Yup, I added the Terminal command to set it too.